# Do app developers have the option to prevent their Dock icon being "pinned" by user?

Tags: big-sur, dock, icon

Our team is now working on a macOS app. When Users use a specific service, the main process will start another process, and at the same time, generate a new dock icon.

Problem: if this new dock icon being pinned (kept in the Dock) by users, this icon cannot be released, which will leave a useless icon in the Dock after this service process quits.

Is there any way to keep the Dock icon from being pinned by users with some programming method?

Comment: Why does it have a dock icon in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no option for app developers to keep their icon from being pinned by the user.

The app developer should instead ensure that the secondary process does not come with its own Dock icon.